# How to optimize an Illustrator .pdf loading?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, pdf

I am working in Illustrator and would like to export vector objects as a .pdf. These vector objects are overlapping one another in some areas. This creates a problem when I open the .pdf, it seems to load the bottom objects first before the top objects (See image below). I would like to some how create a "flat .pdf" so everything loads at once. I need the PDF to display in vector, a pixel based .pdf will not work for my project.

[image]

[image]

I include a link to a .pdf to test, https://adobe.ly/2v90Ikg

Comment: Hi driverpizza, check if from the **Layers Panel Menu** > **Flatten Artwork** help to get a quality PDF. Duplicate the file if necessary.

Comment: @Danielillo Unfortunately that did not work...

Comment: The problem is not the AI layers, is the .pdf loading. Maybe you should check different .pdf options to change this. How big the .pdf is and how big your final work must be?

Comment: I've tried a few options for exporting as pdf without layers and flattening layers in acrobat, but for some reason it still treats the objects the same.

Comment: @Danielillo I also reduced the file size in half and it still doesn't load as one.

Comment: Did you try **Reduce Size PDF** or **Optimized PDF** from Acrobat and the re-open the optimized .pdf?

Comment: @Danielillo yes, it seems to still be having trouble...

Comment: Ok, I check in internet, there are several forums on that topic without any solution. Try a new pdf with the **Document Raster Effect Setting** to 72 ppi from the **Effect Menu**.

Comment: @Danielillo Unfortunately, still not loading as a whole.

Comment: How big is your file in inches or millimeters?

Comment: @Danielillo 4.5in x 8in

Comment: I include a tester pdf at your question with the same issue. Feel free to remove it if it does not fit what you request in the question.

Comment: @driverpizza I can't open the PDF linked in your quesiton.  Adobe reader says "not a supported file type" or the "file has been damaged".

Comment: @BillyKerr Try it once more, it works on my end, and I did not place that .pdf, someone else edited the question including it.

Comment: @driverpizaa - nope, still not working in Adobe Reader.

Comment: @BillyKerr just right click to the link and open it in a new browser tab or window

Comment: @Danielillo - I don't generally view PDFs in my browser. I know it works in Firefox's own viewer, but the file doesn't open in Adobe Reader DC, and it should, if it's a PDF. So, this seems to be indicative of an error of some kind in the PDF file itself.

Comment: @BillyKerr It's a .pdf from an online application viewer, not a "pure" pdf. I tried to download it and open it in Acrobat and does't work too. I add it just to see it online. If you know other way to share a .pdf tell me the link and I upload it.

Comment: @Danielillo - you could share a real PDF via Adobe Creative Cloud, or Microsoft One Drive, Google Drive etc.

Comment: @BillyKerr .pdf link updated at the question, Adobe Creative Cloud.

Comment: @Danielillo - yes that one works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no solution to this problem! There are 3 reasons for this.

1. The data in the PDF is written bottom object up.

   Yes they have to be separate objects otherwise thy cant have different colors. grouping wont help they still are separate inside the group.
2. The rasterizer that produces the image i essentially using painters algorithm to solve the issue. It really has to draw back to front. But even if it wasn't the AA would still need to sort each fragment. So even if the renderer wasn't showing you the effect halfway that is still what it would be doing.
3. You have no control over the setup of you users PDF viewer, if the viewer opts to refresh drawing on screen even unfinished that's it. There is no instruction in PDF format specs for instructing PDF to do anything else.

   So how it works is entirely up to the software that renders the PDF. PDF.js definitely does this refreshing.

Comment: Although , came to think of it. if you put all your data inside a clipping mask then it could force some renderers to cache the entire thing. by no means bulletproof but worth  a try.

Answer (score 0):

### Please make a copy of the file before continuing.

**Object > Flatten Transparency...** can help merge these layers together but it is very difficult to edit the file afterward. Backing up the original would be recommended.

Use the **High Resolution** preset for the best quality.

[image: transparency flattener]

All the elements are now merged to one layer as one object.

[image: all elements in one layer]

Comment: After trying your answer, it also does not offer the solution to the problem. I think the solution, if it exists, is much more complex. Some internet forums offer to remove all Acrobat plugins to have a faster loading, but I don't think it is viable to ask whoever sees your .pdf to modify their application before opening the file.

Comment: This still does not work, the pdf wants to load the bottom objects first still.

Comment: Just curious: what is the intended use of this illustration that it needs to remain in vector format? I don't know that you ever shared that.

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is save your illustration as jpeg and then covert it to pdf. You're welcome

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Unfortunately this doesn't answer the question. The OP says "I need the PDF to display in vector". So, converting artwork to JPEG first will not resolve the problem.